# Como fazer o Hibernate "perceber" que o valor de uma coluna foi setada pelo banco de dados

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Minha tabela no banco de dados tem uma coluna que é preenchida automaticamente pelo próprio banco de dados.

Essa tabela está mapeada como uma classe anotada com @Entity, chamada `EntidadeA`. A coluna que é preenchida automaticamente está mapeada em uma propriedade anotada com @Column, chamada `prop1`.

Ao executar `EntityManager.persist(objeto)`, com a propriedade `prop1` = `null`, o hibernate executa um `INSERT INTO tb... (coluna_prop1, ...) values (NULL, ...)` no banco de dados.
Nesse momento o banco de dados seta um valor YYY na coluna_prop1.

**Pergunta:** Como fazer o hibernate reler do banco de dados, imediatamente após o persist, o valor de **uma coluna**?

Obs: Atualmente executo `EntityManager.refresh(objeto)` logo após o persist() --- funciona, mas isso faz o hibernate reler **todas** as propriedades do banco de dados (ie. ineficiente).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Hibernate possui uma anotação proprietária para lidar com valores gerados, [@Generated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Generated.html). Ela é pouco conhecida, mas faz exatamente o que você quer ([documentação oficial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-generated)).

```java
// Valores gerados tanto em inserts quanto updates
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS) 
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String propriedade1;

// Valores gerados apenas em inserts
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT) 
@Column(insertable = false)
private String propriedade2;
```

Comment: tiagoinu, está aqui o modo de controlar o "item 1" da outra resposta

Comment: Spark, na verdade essa opção não faz com que a aplicação altere o banco de dados. Ela é a contrapartida do item 2, fazendo o "refresh" automático das colunas marcadas para tipos simples pré-configurados (pense no [getGeneratedKeys()](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/oracle-java-jdbc-get-primary-key-insert-sql/) do JDBC).

Answer (score 2):

O JPA/Hibernate apenas mapeia toda alteração que passar por ele.

Ao realizar qualquer alteração via banco de dados o Hibernate não fica ciente que houve essa alteração.

Na verdade, te aconselho a tomar bastante cuidado com isso pois é uma má prática.

Se você não der sempre o refresh na entidade outro usuário pode ficar com a versão desatualizada do objeto o que poderia causar inconsistência de dados.

Soluções seriam:

1. Não deixar o banco de dados alterar o valor, mas colocar essa lógica no seu projeto
2. Dar o refresh no entidade para buscar o valor correto

Comment: +1 no item 1. Fazer a lógica em um callback de save para gravar os dados corretamente e em um sistema de vários acessos simultâneos não deixar models em cache, sempre buscar da base.

Comment: Item 2 então, pois não controlo o item 1. Refresh() imediatamente após Persist() é feio, pois acabei de criar o objeto, mas já que é a única solução...